# weak convergence and limit

Tags: real-analysis, weak-convergence

This problem is in Real Analysis H.L. Royden 4th edition(pearson modern classic) No.25 at page 171.

> Let X be normed linear space and for each $x \in X$, there is a bounded linear functional $T_{f} \in X^{*}$ such that $T_{f}(f)=||f||$ and $\|T_{f} \|_{*}=1$. Prove that if $\{f_{n}\}$ weakly converge to both $g_{1},g_{2}$, then $g_{1}=g_{2}$.

Here is my approach.
Since $\{f_{n}\}$ weakly converge to both $g_{1},g_{2}$, $T(f_{n}) \rightarrow T(g_{1})$ and $T(f_{n})\rightarrow T(g_{2})$ for **every** bounded linear functional on $X$. I know that $T(f_{n})$ is sequence on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff space, so I can conclude that $T(g_{1})=T(g_{2})$. So $T(g_{1}-g_{2})=0$ always.
Since $T($**0**$)=0$, I can conclude that $g_{1}=g_{2}$ if I can get a contradiction by assuming the contrary. I can guess that "$g_{1},g_{2}$ have same norm in $X$ thinking about assumptions in the problem, but still I can't prove that $g_{1}=g_{2}$. How can I approach to the next step?

Comment: Using Hahn-Banach, if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are distinct, there is a bounded linear functional that takes the value $1$ at one of them and the value $0$ on the other.

Comment: I wanted to use Hahn-Banach, but I can't even understand **statement** of theorem :(

Answer (score 1):

I concluded. $T(g_{1})=T(g_{2})$ is equivalent to $T(g_{1}-g_{2})=0$, taking linear functional $T_{g}$ by assumption of the problem such that $T(g_{1}-g_{2})=\|g_{1}-g_{2}\|_{X}$, so I get $\|g_{1}-g_{2}\|_{X}=0$. Thus by the definition of **norm**, $g_{1}-g_{2}=$**0**$_{X}$, and $g_{1}=g_{2}$.